# regarding list object's attributes

Tags: python, list, attributes, strip

While I am writing this code `lst=list(map(int,input().split().strip()))` then I am getting an `AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute strip`

But it is working when I remove the `strip()` method.
My question is that list object also has no attribute `split`. So in this case `(lst=list(map(int,input().split()))` why it is not giving any error and why it is giving error in case of `strip()` method?

Comment: Because `input().split()` gives you a list that you then try to `strip()` which is not valid. Do `input().strip().split()`. If you're confused by code that's been stuffed into one line, it often helps to unravel that code out over multiple lines to understand what it's doing

Answer (score 1):

Before you read the rest of the answer: you shouldn't have to `strip()` after you call `split()` because `split()` will consider multiple whitespace characters as a single delimiter and automatically remove the extra whitespace. For example, this snippet evaluates to `True`:

```
s1 = "1 2 3"
s2 = "1       2       3"
s3 = "   1   2   3   "

s1.split() == s2.split() == s3.split()
```

---

`split()` and `strip()` are both attributes of *string* objects!

When you're confused by code that's been stuffed into one line, it often helps to unravel that code out over multiple lines to understand what it's doing

Your line of code can be unraveled like so:

```
user_input_str = input()

split_input_list = user_input_str.split()

stripped_input = split_input_list.strip() ### ERROR!!!

lst = list(map(int, stripped_input))
```

Clearly, you tried to access the `strip()` method of a `list` object, and you know that doesn't exist.

In your second example, you do

```
user_input_str = input()

split_input_list = user_input_str.split()

lst = list(map(int, split_input_list))
```

Which works perfectly fine because you don't try to access `strip()` on a `list` object

Now to fix this, you need to change the order of operations: first, you get your input. Next, strip it. This gives you back a string. *Then*, split this stripped string.

```
user_input_str = input()

stripped_input_str = user_input_str.strip() ### No error now!

split_input_list = stripped_input_str.split()

lst = list(map(int, split_input_list))

#or in one line:
lst = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
```

Or, if you want to strip *each element of the split input list*, you will need to map the `strip()` function to `split_input_list` like so:

```
user_input_str = input()
split_input_list = user_input_str.split()

stripped_input_list = list(map(str.strip, split_input_list))

lst = list(map(int, stripped_input_list))

#or in one line
lst = list(map(int, map(str.strip, input().split())))

# or, create a function that calls strip and then converts to int, and map to it
def stripint(value):
    return int(value.strip())

lst = list(map(stripint, input().split()))
```